# How to establish a secure VNC tunnel between two hosts behind NAT?

Tags: linux, xorg, nat, vnc, ssh-tunnel

How can I establish a secure tunnel for `VNC` from my home computer my computer in the office, both hosts are behind NAT. I do have ssh access to the machine at work (I have established a reverse ssh tunnel (using `autossh`) to a host with a public IP).  All involved machines are running Linux. I need X11 access to my work computer, using the `-X` flag with ssh works but is way too slow.

As @satwell suggested, I did the second proposed solution:

```
work$ ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 public
home$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 public
```

which seemed to work great and let me connect from home, only the screen I got looked like:
[image]
how do I get access to the actual (unity) desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC operates over port numbers starting at 5900.  (VNC :0 is port 5900, VNC :1 is port 5901, etc.)  Assuming your work machine is using :0 for VNC, then you'll need to forward port 5900.

If you already having a working ssh tunnel that lets you connect from `home` to `work` (via intermediate machine `public`), then you just need to add `-L 5900:localhost:5900` to whatever ssh command you run on `home` to connect to `work`.  Then you can VNC to `localhost:0` on `home`.

This is the most secure option because your traffic is encrypted end-to-end between `home` and `work`, but it does mean that you have two layers of SSH tunnels.

If you prefer, you could instead set up two separate tunnels, one between `home` and `public`, and a second between `work` and `public`.  This may be slightly faster, but be aware that the security of this alternative depends on the security of `public`.  In this version, anyone who can send traffic to `localhost` on `public` can connect to port 5900 on `work`.  And `root` on `public` can inspect all of your VNC traffic.

```
work$ ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 public
home$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 public
```

You can optionally use `autossh` for either or both of these tunnels.

Comment: Awesome, great! Thanks for this but how do I get access to the actual desktop, please see my update above.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the X session not starting correctly inside VNC.  Maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts will help?

Comment: yes, i've been looking at different `xstartup` configurations already (including the one from the link) but could not get it to work yet. One thing that i changed from your proposal is, i forwarded port `5901` instead of `5900` as my server is started on `5901`, but i think the actual tunneing works as expected - I accepted your answer! Thanks!